# CopyIntoItems Sharepoint SOAP Action Parameters

Tags: sharepoint, http, post, soap, http-headers

I am trying to upload a file using SOAP Action

```
POST /_vti_bin/Copy.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: my.hostname.net
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <SourceUrl>string</SourceUrl>
      <DestinationUrls>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </DestinationUrls>
      <Fields>
        <FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter or Choice or Lookup or Boolean or Number or Currency or URL or Computed or Threading or Guid or MultiChoice or GridChoice or Calculated or File or Attachments or User or Recurrence or CrossProjectLink or ModStat or AllDayEvent or Error" DisplayName="string" InternalName="string" Id="guid" Value="string" />
        <FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter or Choice or Lookup or Boolean or Number or Currency or URL or Computed or Threading or Guid or MultiChoice or GridChoice or Calculated or File or Attachments or User or Recurrence or CrossProjectLink or ModStat or AllDayEvent or Error" DisplayName="string" InternalName="string" Id="guid" Value="string" />
      </Fields>
      <Stream>base64Binary</Stream>
    </CopyIntoItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I wish to upload a PDF file or Doc file. I am using Firefox extension Poster

I have the source and destination URLs

What should be the values of `<FieldInformation>` and `<Stream>` ?

Thanks in advance

Viv

Answer (score 0):

The stream value needs to be the base64binary representation of the file. So for example I have a text file that contains the text "123". Using this site http://www.base64converter.com/ I converted the text to base64 which translated to "MTIz". So if I was trying to upload my file I would put "MTIz" (without quotes) into the Stream tag. Something like this:

```
<Stream>MTIz</Stream>
```

The FieldInformation tags need to contain any SharePoint properties that need to be associated with the document you are uploading. So if you want to set the title property to "My Document" you would need something like this:

```
<FieldInformation Type="Text" DisplayName="Title" InternalName="Title" Id="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Value="My Document" />
```

Comment: The ID is the guid representation of the field you are trying to update. To find it you can either:
- use a tool like SharePoint Manager to view
- Go to the content type on the list, copy the field url, copy the property after FID and replace %7B with { and %7D with }

Comment: Getting file is corrupt error with the stream. trying to upload pdf file.